$f(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$. Prove that $3 \leq n \implies \frac{n}{\ln(n)} < \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{f(k)}$
$f(n)$ is number of groups of order $n$ up to isomorfism. Prove $$3 \leq n \implies \frac{n}{\ln(n)} < \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{f(k)}$$
Context:
I am studing this function. Searching for interesting properties. Nobody knows an efficient method to find the number of groups in general. I already know that $f(n)$ cannot be expressed as a finite degree polynomial function.
Let $p$ a prime number. Let $m$ a positive integer. I already know that:
$$p^{\frac{2}{27}m^{2}(m-6)} \leq f(p^{m})$$
Then $f(n)$ grows really fast for some cases. I was wondering if
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f(k)}$$
converges. I thought that to search a lower bound would help me.
Current Progress:
This is a solved problem.

Let's define functions:
$$g_{0}(n) := \frac{1}{f(n)}$$
$$g_{1}(n) := \sum_{k=1}^{n}g_{0}(k)$$
$$g_{2}(n) := \left\{
\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    1, & \text{if $n$ is a prime number} \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.$$
$$g_{3}(n) := \sum_{k=1}^{n}g_{2}(k)$$
$$g_{2}(n) \leq g_{0}(n) \implies g_{3}(n) \leq g_{1}(n)$$
$g_{3}$ is the prime counting function. For $17 \leq n$:
$$\frac{n}{\ln(n)} < g_{3}(n) \leq g_{1}(n) \implies \frac{n}{\ln(n)} < g_{1}(n)$$
The inequality is also true for $3 \leq n \leq 16$.
